# make div of full width inside of a bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am already inside a container of fixed with  and i am trying to insert a parallex of full width.

> **Problem** : I couldn't make it of full width as its inside a container. The parallax div is a static block comes form backend. [So
>   as i try to close container inside static block it automatically
>   removes the unpaired closing div]

I tried making it's positing absolute wrapping it with a div of position relative:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="parallax-wrapper">          //position: relative;
        <div class="parallax-container">    //position: absolute;
           //parallax div and content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And also this limits within the container only.

Visually, below i need to make the parallax of full width indicated by green lines.

[image]

*The Only solution i have now is via jquery, first obtaining document width. And by subtracting it form the current container width and adding remaining width and make it fixed width and let it overflow managing margin to left negatively. and i don't think its a good practice*

Comment: have tow divs. One with container and another without container which will be of full width

Comment: @AnkushJain the parallax is inside a container. Container is a parent div and parallax as child.

Comment: Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/r1q0gyhp/1/). Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: who would upvote a question that goes against the parent child relationship of css? This is a problem due to a lack of planning

Comment: @Christina , this is something called as hacks i guess [And often needs while using other's CMS]. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I made it even, neither up or down. Use jQuery: http://jsbin.com/fucevi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the jquery solution you described with css, but for IE9 +.

```
.parallax-container{
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}

.parallax-container:before,
.parallax-container:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.parallax-container:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

You can read about vw [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) and about calc() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar approach however I needed an element that would expand full width that was inside of a container + column.

I wasn't able to move my whole DOM structure around because I had a floating sticky sidebar I needed to account for which calculates its place on the page based on offsets of the right sidebar relative to the top/bottom of my page.

I came up with an alternative solution which should help if you have this similar structure:

```
<div class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="full-width">
              <nav class="nav">
                [..z-index above pseudo element]
              </nav>
              [...bg light]
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="full-width">
              [...make full width with white bg via pseudo element]
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
        [...sticky sidebar]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.full-width {
  position: relative;

  .nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  &:after {
    content: '';
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999em;
    right: -999em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has an innovative but simple solution
Write your code like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="bg-warning">
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
          has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- This is our full width container -->
      <div class="container-fluid bg-white">
        <div class="container">
          <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
            It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
            making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="container">
        <p>
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It
          has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
          it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- This is a simple container -->
      <div class="container bg-white">
          <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
            It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
            making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor

          </p>
  
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```