# how to cancel left and right margin to have a 100% wide image

Tags: html, css, image, margin

i have an question about css,

I have a margin which is 18px on the right and on the left of the page on a section
I need to be able to bypass this rule so that an image (a child) can be 100% wide

if i use negative marging it doesn't work, if i use 100vw it adds a scroll bar

how do i get an image that is the full width of the page?

here an example https://codepen.io/astr0cd/pen/YzqXmEp

```css
.section {
  margin: 60px 18px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: -18px;
  margin-right: -18px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="#" class="image">
</div>
```

Comment: width:calc(100% + 36px)

Comment: in addition to what Temani said, I think this post answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838570/make-div-of-full-width-inside-of-a-bootstrap-container

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `margin-right: -18px` and change the width as `calc(100% + 36px)`. Also you should set the `margin:0` to `body`, not to `html`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.section {
  margin: 60px 18px;
}

.image {
  width: calc(100% + 36px);
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: -18px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="section">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="#" class="image">
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below. Pay attention to how `.image` class works. In this case no matter how much margin `.section` class have the `.image` will be at 100% `width`

```css
.section{
    margin: 60px 18px;  
}
.image {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="#" class="image">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use and absolute positioning.
.image {
position: absolute;
...other codes
}